# GoogleAPI Sheets API - captcha

Tags: google-sheets-api

We have recently been blocked whist accessing the GoogleSheets API V4.

On calling the batchUpdate endpoint we are being served a 503 and the html body is a captcha challenge.

Does anyone know how we can remove this block on our API access?

Comment: Could you add some additional information about your error so that the community will be able check?